# XDocument compared to var

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

In various articles I see 2 different notations which look very similar and appear to produce the exact same results.

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("Settings.xml");
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("Settings.xml");
```

What is the difference between them, if any? and which is preferred?

Comment: There's no difference, with `var` the compiler automatically deduces the type from the expression on the right (type inference). That saves you from writing out `XDocument` as the variable type. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx.

Comment: @Maximilian. Clear. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Gilad. Thanks for pointing that out. Must have missed it. Shall I remove this post?

Comment: @JoeyJoystick - No :) I think having duplicate questions that refer back to the "original" are good - make search easier. I do think that editing the title of this question to specify that you are asking `XDocument` compared to `var` is important though